# How is the time stamp number in /etc/shadow calculated?

Tags: posix

On my system the man page of shadow defines the third column value this way:

> The date of the last password change, expressed as the number of
>   days since Jan 1, 1970.

I have an example value "17050". `passwd -S` says this is the "2016-09-06". But the seconds since 1970 are "1473112800.0". When I calculate 1473112800.0/(60*60*24) I get "17049.9166666666".

How is the "17050" calculated? Is it rounded or is it always the next greater integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the source code (for the Debian version), it’s just [scaled](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/blob/589f97ade4610b98cc532c8142343d4c33694e72/src/passwd.c#L671) using integer division by [24 × 3600](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/shadow/blob/589f97ade4610b98cc532c8142343d4c33694e72/lib/defines.h#L282), so it’s truncated.

Note that the value you have is exactly two hours off in your calculation, which can probably be explained by timezone variations.

Answer (score 3):

It's a number of days, not seconds, since the epoch.

```
$ date -I -d '1970-01-01 + 17050 days'
2016-09-06
```

(As a side note, technically you can't represent "365 days from now" in seconds; days do not have a fixed or even knowable length beyond 6 months out, due to leap seconds.)

Comment: If it is not possible to know the length of a day, how is the value in /etc/shadow calculated?

Comment: @ceving the value is stored in days, not seconds, so there is no need to calculate it. Other than that, I suspect the code just ignores the problem, like most everyone.

Comment: The (for example) Linux kernel runs with a [250Hz timer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14925568/402322). All time in the Linux kernel is a multiple of 0.004 seconds. And this means every value in days must be calculated by a value in seconds.

Comment: @ceving The realtime clocks (there are more than one, not all run at 250Hz, but that's not really relevant) all measure *past* days. We know the length of past days, but not (certain) future days. Even that, though, they don't actually do; `date +%s` does not actually give the number of seconds since Jan 1 1970 0000Z; it's currently 27s short. Most recently, there is no `date +%s` for 2016-12-31 23:59:60Z